# POST unchecked checkboxes with hidden elements

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox

I know there are other posts with the same question but it doesn't work for me. 
Well, I have a database table (image) with 'img_name' and 'img_status'. Status can be 'active' or 'inactive'. In php I do following, to set the image in DB to active or inactive:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($images)) {
    if ($row->img_status == 'active') {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="image[]" value="' . $row->img_name . '">';
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="image[]" value="' . $row->img_name . '" checked> ' . $row->img_name . '</label>';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="image[]" value="' . $row->img_name . '">';
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="image[]" value="' . $row->img_name . '"> ' . $row->img_name . '</label>';
    }
}
```

For rows with active status the checkbox is checked and for inactive its unchecked. 
On submitting form I do:

```
    if(isset($_POST['image']) && is_array($_POST['image'])) {
        foreach($_POST['image'] as $imageName) {
            // here i want update table 
            // unchecked: set image to inactive
            // checked: set image to active
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is, when I uncheck one which was checked (because in database its active and hence on pageload its checked) and submit the form, it doesn't post.

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work". What do you get and what you expected to get?

Comment: sorry, I accidentally saved the incomplete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you need to the hidden fields, but if you are going to use then, give them a different name:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($images)) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="allimage[]" value="' . $row->img_name . '">';
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="image[]" value="' . $row->img_name . '" ' . ($row->img_status == 'active' ? 'checked' : '') . '> ' . $row->img_name . '</label>';
}
```

Then, when you get the return values, $_POST['allimage'] has all of the images and $_POST['image'] has the ones that are checked. Then:

```
array_intersect($_POST{'allimage'], $_POST['image']);
```

has all of the images that were checked, and

```
array_diff($_POST{'allimage'], $_POST['image']);
```

returns an array of all of the names that were not checked. You can then go through and set their status to "Active" or "Disabled" as required.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create a column called status and make it a tinyint with a value of 1 and if the image status is 0 it means it's not active and if it is 1 then it is active then you can use radio buttons instead of checkbox like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value="0"<?php if ($row["status"] == 0) { echo "checked"; } ?> />

<input type="radio" name="status" value="1"<?php if ($row["status"] == 1) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
```

and in your while loop you can also do this to display text instead of the numbers and echo it where ever you want or need:

```
$stat = $row['status'];
    if($stat == 0) {
       $status = "Disabled";
    } else {
        $status = "Active";
    }
```